# How to set the state of the child component and the parent component correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below example, I am trying to do the following:

- I have input fields, I want to capture the changes I make to these inputs in an object in the form: `{ id: value, id: value, ...etc }`, I can then send this data structure to a service to do... whatever :)

I am having problems with the implementation:

- When the input field changes for the *Input* component, I need to manage the `onChange` via setState which is typical to do in React. However, I also need to capture the changes made to the input fields.
- To capture the changes, I am using the *Parent* component to handle a callback function, which will update the state with the new changes.
- Additionally, I am only allowing the user to submit the changes if new changes exist. Keeping it simple for now, with a button to be enabled when new changes exist.

**TLDR**: I believe something is wrong with my use of set state, I am trying to set the state in the child, and in the parent via a callback function. However one is taking priority over the other, both set states are no executing. Why is this and how can implement this correctly?

Note: this is pseudocode, please forgive any typos made, I tried to keep it as real as possible.

- Submit Component

```
class Submit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { showButton } = this.props;

        return (
            <button type='button' disabled={!showButton}>
                Hello world!
            </button>
        );
    }

);
```

- Input Component

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { enable } = this.props;
        const id = e.target.id;
        const value = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            [id]: value
        });

        enable(id, value); // <- Using this here breaks set state.
    }

    render() {
        const { myName } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='name' onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='' />
                <input type='text' id='address' onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='' />
                <!-- there can be more input fields -->
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

- Parent Component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            enableButton: false,
            inputFieldValues: {},
        };
    }

    enable = (value) => {
        const { inputFieldValue } = this.state;
        let changes = inputFieldValues || {};

        changes[key] = value;

        this.setState({
            enableButton: true,
            inputFieldValues: changes
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { enableButton } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Input enable={this.enable} />
                <Submit enableButton={enableButton} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you notice if you're getting a JS error in the browser console?

Comment: I am not, what happens is that within `onChange`, `this.setState` is triggering for the Parent, but not for the Input component. If instead I type `() => enable(id. value);` the Input component triggers a set state, but the Parent component does not trigger its own setState for the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I've understood your problem, but here is fixed example of you pseudo-code.

What I've noticed:

```
const { inputFieldValue } = this.state;
let changes = inputFieldValues || {};

changes[key] = value;
```

I don't know whether you make the same mistake in your real app, but I want to mention that this is pretty rude mistake that can to an unexpected behavior, since you mutate the state object, instead of creating new one. React compares objects references, it doesn't make deep checks of them.
This `let changes = inputFieldValues || {};` should be `let changes = { ...inputFieldValues } || {};`.

Also, you didn't provide field values to your inputs. Although, it doesn't affect state changes, but then inputs and the state can become unsynchronized.

```js
class Submit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { enableButton } = this.props;

    return (
      <button type="button" disabled={!enableButton}>
        Hello world!
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      address: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { enable } = this.props;
    const id = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      [id]: value
    });

    enable(id, value);
  };

  render() {
    const { myName } = this.state;

    console.log("Input:", this.state);

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder=""
          {/* Always provide state values to your inputs to make sure they're always synchronized */}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="address"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder=""
          value={this.state.address}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      enableButton: false,
      inputFieldValues: {}
    };
  }

  enable = (key, value) => {
    const { inputFieldValues } = this.state;
    // Copy objects, when you change their fields.
    let changes = { ...inputFieldValues } || {};

    changes[key] = value;

    this.setState({
      enableButton: true,
      inputFieldValues: changes
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { enableButton } = this.state;

    console.log("Parent:", this.state);

    return (
      <div>
        <Input enable={this.enable} />
        <Submit enableButton={enableButton} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give it a try shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have an error in your code and it isn't reflected in the pseudocode you shared here, but based on it i could make it work, having state properly updated in both parent and children component (check the console.log ).

https://codesandbox.io/s/r79q9myj8o

Comment: Thank you Oscar, I think this is a problem in terms of implementation because on my end, react is giving priority to the set state which occurs first (in the Input component) versus the Parent component. I think I am doing something wrong here